# PIL fonts showing up as squares

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have a program that is supposed to generate an image with a bunch of random symbols randomly placed around it. When I run it, this is what gets created.[image]

The font I'm trying to use is symbol.ttf which I grabbed out of C:\WINDOWS\Fonts

Here's the code I'm using to paste the characters:

```
font = 'fonts/symbol.ttf'  

t = Image.new("RGBA", (300,300))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(t)

font = ImageFont.truetype(font, fontsize)

draw.text((70, 70), txt, (0,0,0), font=font)

t = t.rotate(rot)

image.paste(t,box,t)
```

Comment: You're going to need to post your code.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I accidentally hit enter before I was finished typing it up.

Comment: Is PIL finding the font correctly? Are you pointing at window's Font directory? In my experience access to that directory can be a little funky. When I had to do some PIL work I found this tutorial helpful: http://www.geeks3d.com/20100930/tutorial-first-steps-with-pil-python-imaging-library/ -- they're importing ImageFont and using the ImageFont.load method.

Comment: It should be finding it fine. When it doesn't it should give an error, and it worked fine with some of the other fonts I tried. I copied it out of the fonts directory and into a folder on the desktop. When I try running `font = ImageFont.load(ft)` I get an OSError cannot find glyph data file

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
ImageFont.truetype(font, fontsize, encoding="symb")
```

Comment: In the question the content of txt was not stated. Please, explain in your answer in which cases encoding="symb" is needed.